# Why do i need the import library of a dll that i am not directly calling from my executable?

Tags: c++, dll, linker, shared-libraries

I have a dynamic library **A.dll** that is used by **B.dll**. I am using **B.dll** in an executable **C.exe**.

```
level 0: A.dll
level 1: B.dll
level 2: C.exe
```

I get a linker error in Visual Studio, saying that the linker can not find the import library A.lib, even though my executable is not directly using A.dll. Why is this? I assumed the information in A.lib would be compiled into B.dll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without code my suspicion would be that the public header(s) for B includes the header for A and A's header has a #pragma comment(lib, "a.lib"). The pattern you describe would need B to only depend on A in its private interface rather than expose anything from A directly.